# Review count: separate tag reviews from post reviews?

Tags: support

Is there a way to filter the list of reviews I have done, into tag revisions only, and/or post reviews? So that I can see for example all post reviews listed separately?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to see posts where you've reviewed suggested tag changes _only_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Even if you dig into [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), we lump all review tasks into one category (suggested edit), so you wouldn't be able to sort them.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. Thanks for the info anyway.